# Swift view model: function vs setter with side effect

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, architecture, viewmodel

I need some opinion on view model architecture, in my project I need a view model for a screen that displays a game preparation status, say I need more than 3 players to start game, and the view model has a string property for the status, and I have in my view controller an array of players retrieved from API.

**Option 1:**

```
// `gameStatusLabel` is a get property and only set internally when
// updating players via function
class GameStatusViewModel: NSObject {

  private(set) var gameStatusLabel: String

  func updatePlayers(players: [Player]?) {
    if let players = players, players.count > 3 {
      gameStatusLabel = "Ready to start"
    } else {
      gameStatusLabel = "Not enough player(s)"
  }
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
// `gameStatusLabel` is a computed property based on `players.count`

class GameStatusViewModel {

    weak var players: [Player]?

    var gameStatusLabel: String {
        if let players = self.players {
            if players.count > 3 {
                return "Ready to start"
            }
        }
        return "Not enough player(s)"
    }
}
```

Since I'm new to Swift so I want to ask which option above is better, and why? (or alternatively if there's any other better option)

**Option 1** doesn't store players model in the view model since it doesn't need to keep a reference to `players`, and `players` is only needed for updating the `gameStatusLabel`, whereas **Option 2** keeps a weak reference to players and makes `gameStatusLabel` a computed property, the problem here is that `players` in **Option 2** only need a setter, I don't know if I can have only a setter for a property without a getter (this seems to be the way of **Option 1**).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In my opinion, Option 2 is the better approach, but you really need to use a binding framework with MVVM in order to avoid the issues raised by @test

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems with computed properties is that you are not always aware of them changing. So many programmers are usually hesitant to use them in large projects see [this link](https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-computed-properties/) for more information.